# Angular scope for variable declared inside modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Still learning AngularJS. And i've stumbled upon what seems to me to be yet another AngularJS/JS quirk.

I'm opening a modal with aria tags using bootstrap 3 and angularjs using a button:

```
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test-modal">
    Show modal
</button>
```

Inside my modal, i set a boolean in an ng-repeat tag:

```
<div ng-repeat="test_data in test_array">
    <label>{{test_bool}} - Assertion: {{test_bool == true}}</label>
    <button ng-click="test_bool = !test_bool">Flip</button>
</div>
```

I would expect test_bool to be uninitialized when closing and re-opening the modal, but this isn't the case. Instead, the variables keep their state even though the modal gets closed.

I illustrated it in this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/sO5bAq81OR3oB8O4zHEk?p=preview.

How does angular separate these values when they all have the same name? I know that i can define what scope the modal uses by launching it from JS, but how does that help me when all the values have the same name? The data must be contained in an angular-specific data container that i don't know how to reach.

I usually debug these kinds of problems by printing the variable and looking through it in the console, but for a reason unbeknownst to me, this is not possible with angulars "$" variables.

So to my question: How do i access the variables defined inside the model from my controller code? And how do i ensure that these variables gets cleared everytime i open the modal?

Cheers!